# How do I edit a Business Objects schedule from their RESTful Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, business-objects

I'm working with SAP Business Objects RESTful Web Services and I need to update an existing report. I can see a few pieces of information on what I want but not the whole picture.

In the user guide there is a section on updating properties and it lists those properties. It appears to be an exhaustive list. But what I need is not in there.

My end goal is to pause the report via web services as well as the ability to update items like the recurrance, report format or name of the report to name a few items.

What I'm looking at in the user guide seems to cover the name, but not the others.

What am I missing?

How do I update and/or pause a schedule after it has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, you cannot. The only actions that are available in the REST SDK regarding schedules for Web Intelligence are (up until BI 4.2 SP1):

- Getting the list of schedules
- Getting the details of a schedule
- Adding a schedule
- Deleting a schedule

If you want to update/pause schedules, then you'll need to resort to a different SDK (Java might be an option, although SAP is moving everything towards REST).

Another possibility is that you define these actions in your own application. E.g. updating a schedule could consist of:

1. Getting the details of a schedule
2. Deleting the schedule
3. Adding the schedule (with modifications of the original settings of course).

Comment: We ended up setting the start date to 1/1/2100 and displaying anything with a matching start date as paused. Not too happy with it, but it's 'working'